# Automapper ProjectTo() works only with nullable references (e.g. int?) in integration tests

Tags: c#, automapper, projectto

I have a Web API in .Net 6 with [OData 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio) where I expose DTOs to query on.

My entity looks like:

```
public class MyDbEntity
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   // FK
   public int MyOtherDbEntityId { get; set; }
   public virtual MyOtherDbEntity? MyOtherDbEntity { get; set; }   
}
```

My DTO looks like

```
public class MyDto
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   // FK
   public int MyOtherDbEntityId { get; set; }
   public virtual MyOtherDto? MyOtherDto { get; set; }
}
```

I have used `Project()` to map the Db Entity to the DTO as shown below:

```
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IList<MyDto>> Get()
{
   return await DbContext.Set<MyDbEntity>()
         .ProjectTo<MyDto>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
         .ToListAsync();
}
```

The API works fine when I run it.

But when I write [Integration Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory) with mocked database (in memory), the `ProjectTo()` does not return Dtos. The only way to get it to work is to make the Foreign Key nullable as shown below.

My entity with nullable FK :

```
public class MyDbEntity
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   // FK nullable
   public int? MyOtherDbEntityId { get; set; }
   public virtual MyOtherDbEntity? MyOtherDbEntity { get; set; }   
}
```

My DTO with nullable FK:

```
public class MyDto
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   // FK nullable
   public int? MyOtherDbEntityId { get; set; }
   public virtual MyOtherDto? MyOtherDto { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a better way to deal with this other than making the FK nullable? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Your best bet is to use the same database as production in your tests. A less safe version is an in-memory database like SQLite, but the in-memory provider is too far from the real thing to be of much use.